# Wordpress: !empty($title) returns 1 when $title is empty

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on revamping a site and discovered a strange quirk.

In the widget function (found in `default-functions.php`) code, there is a line that says:

```
if ( !empty( $title ) ) { echo $before_title . '[' . $title . '] ' . $after_title; }

function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract($args);
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );
        $text = apply_filters( 'widget_text', empty( $instance['text'] ) ? '' : $instance['text'], $instance );
        echo $before_widget;
        if ( !empty( $title ) ) { echo $before_title . '[' . $title . '] ' . $after_title; } ?>
            <div class="textwidget"><?php echo !empty( $instance['filter'] ) ? wpautop( $text ) : $text; ?></div>
        <?php
        echo $after_widget;
    }
```

The boolean at the `!empty($title)` is supposed to pass a 0 if the $title has no value, but for some reason, it returns a 1. I have looked in the database and everything and can not ascertain what is the challenge.

(I added the brackets to test the issue)

Additional debugging:

- I have turned off all of the plugins
- I have checked and the value of `''` is given to `$title`
- When I swap `empty( $instance['title'] )` for `empty( $title )`, the code works (no titles show on the text widgets)
- When I print out `$title`, I see a space.
- On another instance of WP, I have no problem with this code.

Any ideas friends? I do have PHP Text Widget installed, but it is using the stock textwidget codebase.

Comment: What does var_dump($title) and var_dump(!empty($title)) print?

Comment: @Sanford when you say that `"` is given to `$title` are you saying an empty string or literally quotes?

Comment: @RUJordan I mean that, in the code (see where `$title` is set), there is the standard empty string.  But when I ran the code again, this time with a `strcmp` on the `$title` and the `$instance('title')`, the two values for when it is empty are different.

Comment: @Rangad - running the two calls gives: 

Var Dump title: string(1) " " 
Var Dump !empty(title): bool(true)

Comment: So your string is not empty. See @Uthr 's answer for that.

Comment: @Rangad - the problem is that the code for setting $title is here: 

`$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );`

What does not make sense is why, two lines later, the value is not set at a blank value.  Why would that happen?

Answer (score 1):

you may check what `apply_filters` does, but i'm quite sure in my WP related memories that it adds some html around the value it is passed.

`$instance['title']` is the value of the title of the post that comes from DB.

`$title` however , is the result of `apply_filters` call some lines before your test.

So you have to test against  `$instance['title']` rather than `$title`

Comment: Okay- so I spent more time and now understand you are onto something.  The real question is why is this NOW giving an extra space as the value of the output when the apply_filters should give a blank when the `$instance['title']` is blank as well.

Comment: apply_filters calls plugins to process the value that it is passed. So some plugin you installed or created performs some default formatting on the title even when empty.

Comment: Only issue I have is that I have disabled all plugins.  So not sure what is modifying it - in the midst of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If the string checked by empty() has whitespace, then it returns `false`. You'll need to use something like `$trimmedTitle = trim($title); if(empty($trimmedTitle)) { doStuff(); }` to get rid of the whitespace.

Comment: thanks for the guidance.  The real problem is that one one platform (where I have the production WP running) the same codebase is not causing this problem.  So modifying the WP standard code will not work.  And the strange thing is - there is NO value in the widget title at all anyway.  Not sure how to clear it out, if it is in the database, since I explored the data base and there are no spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  Or I should say @Otto found the solution.

It was here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21430

He helped me look at the `$wp_filter` and discover that Elegant Themes (the theme producer) added a space into the $title for their own theme.